# Intercepting a push notification when the app is not in foreground or background

Tags: push-notification, swift2

My app handles/intercepts push notifications correctly in the following scenarios:
1. App is in foreground/active
2. Opening a push notification from the notification
3. Opening the app from App Icon when badge is visible & the app is in background

All of the above are handled via a check for badge number != 0 in the following:

```
applicationWillEnterForeground
applicationDidBecomeActive
application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

And I even run a check in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` just in case.

However, the following scenario results in the app not intercepting the Push:

1. App was not running for a while (let's for a day)
2. A push is sent, received and a non-zero notification badge is visible
3. The user launches the app from the App icon

In this scenario, the check I have for `badge number != 0` does not get triggered (otherwise the push would have been intercepted).

What else do I need to do in my App to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

As push notification delivery is done on a best effort basis, I added a method on the server to record the last point in time new data was made available. On the app side, I check for push and as a last resort (i.e. if push was not detected), I check with the server if new data is available. If it is, I trigger data download.

This means that in the majority of cases, I can rely on the push but when it fails (for whatever reason) a quick check with the server allows the app to remain in sync (i.e. trigger data download if needed).

I have added extra logic in the app to ensure that if the push hits the user later, the app will not trigger data download unless data signature (CoreData vs. Last push recorded on the server) indicates that there's a need to do so.

While this is not the solution I was after, it is much more reliable.